# finding the maximum length of lists in c#

Tags: c#, list

After I have created a list and added the contents to it, how can I find the length of the list?

Answer (score 59):

Try this:

```
Int32 length = yourList.Count;
```

In C#, arrays have a `Length` property, anything implementing [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) (including `List<T>`) will have a `Count` property.

Answer (score 10):

[`List<T>.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Example:

```
List<string> A = new List<string>();
int Length_A = A.Count;
```

Answer (score 5):

You look to property `size`, then property `length`. But in `c#` its [`Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2#properties)

[MSDN screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7irm.png)

Answer (score 1):

Example: Let we are creating a `List` with some `string` named `vec`. Then `Add` 3 `string` and see the `size` using `vec.Count`.

```
List<string> vec = new List<string>();      
vec.Add("Md.");        
vec.Add("Ahsan");          
vec.Add("Habib");           
Console.WriteLine(vec.Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

You look to property size, then property length. But in c# its Count

```
myList.ToArray().Length
```